# Pandas DataFrame ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

For a current project, I am planning to run a scikit-learn Stochastic Graduent Booster algorithm over a CSV set that includes numerical data.

When calling `line sgbr.fit(X_train, y_train)` of the script, I am however receiving a `ValueError: could not convert string to float:` with no further details given on the respective area that cannot be formatted.

So far, I have among others tried to solve things through a conversion with `pd.to_numeric(df.column.str, errors='coerce')`, which has however led to a follow-on errror `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'drop'` due to the transition from a pandas DataFrame to a numpy array.

Does anyone have an idea why the ValueError is appearing without further positional indication?

The CSV file looks as follows:

[image]

The relevant code section looks like this:

```
# Load CSV and fill empty cells
Germany = pd.read_csv('./Germany_filtered.csv', index_col=0)
Germany = Germany.fillna("")

# Select relevant dependent variable
X = Germany.drop('Status', axis='columns')
y = Germany['Status']

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=2)

from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor

# Instantiate sgbr
sgbr = GradientBoostingRegressor(max_depth=4, n_estimators=200, subsample=0.9,
                                 max_features=0.75, random_state=2)

# Fit sgbr to the training set
sgbr.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: `Germany = Germany.fillna("")` is going to fill empty values with a string.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful input. I have to fill the empty cells though as I am otherwise receiving a NaN related error. Is there any other viable way to fill these cells?

Comment: Note: if it fills the cells with a numeric value, it must be something that would not impact the algorithm (as adding zeros would e.g. yield a distorted image of the data set).